# Param count and argument count don't match and sqlsrv_num_rows

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to get the count of rows returned with this code:

```
    $selectLogin = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "user" and access >= 1";
    $queryLogin = sqlsrv_query($conn, $selectLogin);
    $countLogin = sqlsrv_num_rows($conn, $queryLogin);
    echo $countLogin;
```

And I am getting this error when calling the script:

> PHP Fatal error:  Param count and argument count don't match.

Any thoughts? I have tried the GOOGLE but it is not returning anything with solutions.

Comment: Can you please post your real code? The one you've posted should trigger `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'user' (T_STRING)`, not the error you quote.

Comment: This is what I ended up having to do, it works and I hope that it is right:

        $selectLogin = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $queryLogin = sqlsrv_query($conn, $selectLogin, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'buffered'));
        $countLogin = sqlsrv_num_rows($queryLogin);

Thank you everyone that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$selectLogin = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'user' and access >= 1";
```

If you have `$user` variable already available.. Try like this

```
 $selectLogin = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$user' and access >= 1";
```

Comment: The question is not even about MySQL. SQLSRV has prepared statements and they should be used. Injecting raw `$user` into query will lead to blatant SQL injection.

Comment: I tried the prepare statement just now, and I am receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
        $selectLogin = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? and access >= ? ";
        $params = array('user', '1');
        $queryLogin = sqlsrv_query($conn, $selectLogin, $params);
        $countLogin = sqlsrv_num_rows($conn, $queryLogin);
        echo $countLogin;
```